# Why can't I take directly form Codepen

Tags: css, html, open-source, sublimetext2

I'm trying to use [this](http://codepen.io/ScottMarshall/pen/vAtgB) and create a different landing page utilizing it.

Here is the HTML. The rest is on codepen.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,800,700,900,300,100' rel='stylesheet'        type='text/css'>
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="wrap">
   <h1>Scrolling Form</h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="Username">
<input type="email"placeholder="Password">
<input type="submit" value="Sign In">
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-question"></i>Forgotten Password</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Create an Account</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm fairly new to coding and using Codepen but when I copy the code into Sublime Text 2, it doesn't work.

Why is that and what can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may seem obvious, but if you're copying and pasting that code *exactly* as it appears in the pen, then it isn't working becasue;

1) It's not a full HTML document. It's just a snippet of the body. It need's a doctype, head, body and html tags. Without a complete HTML structure, the browser doesn't treat it as an HTML document.

2) Even if you were creating a full HTML document out of the example, it won't work as-is from Codepen, because Codepen attaches the CSS to the HTML automatically. You would have to link the CSS file in the head of the HTML document for it to work locally.

```
<head>
    <title>Copied from Codepen</title>
    <link href="/style-from-codepen.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Comment: #2 is what I was missing. Thanks for pointing that out - newbie mistake.